# RJSONIO - values containing all characters are not converting to list

Tags: json, r

When I convert JSON that contains characters for all values, my result is a string (not a list). Why? Is there anyway that I can convert this into a list?

Example 1 - mixed value types - converts to a list (great!)

```
> s <- fromJSON('{"key1":true,"key2":"value2"}')
> s
$key1
[1] TRUE

$key2
[1] value2
```

Example 2 - all char values - converts to a character (why?)

```
> s <- fromJSON('{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}')
> s
key1     key2 
"value1" "value2"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `simplify = FALSE` if you want to suppress conversion to vectors.

```
s <- fromJSON('{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}', simplify = FALSE)
> s
$key1
[1] "value1"

$key2
[1] "value2"
```